Make final histogram bin be closed at both ends
I am trying to make a histogram whose final (rightmost) bin includes both its left and right endpoints. I cannot figure out how to do this. In this simple example, we can see that 1, which is on the right endpoint of the sole bucket, is not included in the histogram, as weights is [0] (the bucket has 0 points) instead of [1] (the bucket has 1 point).
julia> using StatsBase

julia> h = fit(Histogram, [1], 0:1)
Histogram{Int64, 1, Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}}}
edges:
  0:1
weights: [0]
closed: left
isdensity: false

In this case I'd hope that any data between 0 and 1, inclusive, would be included in the histogram. Is this possible without manually adding a small amount to the final bucket’s right endpoint or subtracting a small amount from points right on the right endpoint? A solution should be general enough to work with any type of bins that works (Array{Int}, Array{Float64}, anything produced by range, etc).

Just nudge the right edge a bit:
fit(Histogram, [1], [0.0,nextfloat(1.0)])
or if the values are integers, nudge the right edge by 1.

Is there a one-liner to make that work with a range?

Perhaps: eps_extend(rng) = vcat(rng[1:end-1],eltype(rng)<:AbstractFloat ? nextfloat(rng[end]) : rng[end]+1)
